# Where can I find more detailed data on electrictiy usage in preferably hourly time resoultion for Norway?

Tags: data-request, energy

I am working on a research project and I need to find detailed load profiles for electricity usage in industry (also which kind of industry), transport(also which kind) and household in Norway in an hourly or a better resolution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [ENTSOE](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/dashboard/show) has hourly data at the grid level.